# Node-rsa isn't working in react native. But, I've to use it for decryption in Mobile application

Tags: reactjs, react-native, encryption, node-rsa

So, I'm developing a project which needs a website to generate the qr code with encryption and qr code scanner mobile application to scan and decrypt the qr code.

I've used **node-rsa for encryption** in react website.
I've added a feature in site to scan and decrypt the qr code. There it is working fine.

But, when I tried to use node-rsa in react-native application. It's giving error for **constants**, **crypto**, **nodeRsa()**.

I was trying to decrypt the qr code private key that was generated by node-rsa in my react client website.

Can someone help me with my problem?? Thanks in advance!

I've Used this to install node-rsa

```
npm install node-rsa --save
```

[This error is I'm getting in React-native](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aRAK.png)

Comment: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rsa-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rsa-native) try this

Comment: I've tried this library. But the problem was this library uses public key to encrypt the message and decrypt encrypted message by using private key. In node-rsa library, this is opposite. I didn't find any solution to decrypt the message. Now, I have used another library called JSencrypt. This library works well in both react website and react native app.

Answer (score 0):

sorry if I'm a bit late to this question.

The node-rsa library seems to use the `crypto` library under the hood. With NodeJS, crypto comes installed by default, but with React-Native that is not the case.

Here's the link to a similar issue. The problem seems to be with react-native rather than node-rsa. The devs suggest pulling in crypto as a dependency for your project.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9427